# Acumatica foreach best practice

Tags: acumatica

I want to foreach item in SOLine. I should use

```
PXSelectBase<SOLine> lines = new PXSelect<SOLine, Where<SOLine.orderNbr,Equal<Required<SOLine.orderNbr>>>>(graph);

foreach (SOLine item in lines.Select(order.OrderNbr)) {}
```

Or

```
List<SOLine> lines  = PXSelect<SOLine, Where<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderNbr>>>>.Select(graph, order.OrderNbr).FirstTableItems.ToList();

foreach (SOLine item in lines) {}
```

I don't know which is better. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer the first sample, yet mostly for aestetical reasons:

1. It looks easier to read and understand (there's a query in line 1 and next it's executed on database with special parameter)
2. This code does not allocate a List< SOLine> instance that we won't need again later and it won't allocate memory to keep all the rows there, thus asking the CLR only as much memory as a single row takes.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any important difference between the two approaches shown in your examples, aside from that the one with `FirstTableItems` makes you do a couple extra steps - at least invoke this property itself.

I'd recommend to use the first approach with pure `Select(..)` because it is more succinct and does the same thing. `FirstTableItems` would just cast the items of the result set to the type of the first item and provide you with the typed enumerable (`IEnumerable<SOLine>` in your case), but because you do `foreach` over the items casting can be done implicitly - like in your first example. So, better use the simpler option.